# R: Using nested foreach to fill a multidimensional array

Tags: r, multidimensional-array, foreach, nested-loops, doparallel

I am stuck with parallelizing a nested for-loop, which populates a multidimensional array. I am trying to use foreach but have little experience/problems with combining the results/populating the multidimensional array. The conventional approaches with *c*, *cbind*, etc. did not yield the correct results and I could not transfer solutions to similar questions to mine.

For the minimal example, the array is:

```
data<-array(list(),c(3,4,5))
```

The initial nested loops:

```
for ( i in 1:3) { 
 for ( j in 1:5) { 
#here would be a set of functions and large/timely operations which lead to the results A-D and can be parallelized. The results are matrices of different sizes.
    resultA=matrix(c(1:6)*1,nrow=3)
    resultB=matrix(c(1:63)*1,nrow=3)
    resultC=matrix(c(1:12)*1,nrow=3)
    resultD=matrix(c(1:15)*1,nrow=3)
    data[[i,1,j]]=resultA 
    data[[i,2,j]]=resultB
    data[[i,3,j]]=resultC
    data[[i,4,j]]=resultD
  }
}
```

With foreach try no. 1 with *%:%* and *%do%*:

```
library(foreach)

foreach ( i = 1:3) %:%
  foreach ( j = 1:5) %do% { 
    resultA=matrix(c(1:6)*1,nrow=3)
    resultB=matrix(c(1:63)*1,nrow=3)
    resultC=matrix(c(1:12)*1,nrow=3)
    resultD=matrix(c(1:15)*1,nrow=3)
    data[[i,1,j]]=resultA 
    data[[i,2,j]]=resultB
    data[[i,3,j]]=resultC
    data[[i,4,j]]=resultD
  }
```

This variant will write the array correctly and output a list from the foreach function. Here I lack the experience to set or define a correct .combine function.

With foreach try no. 2 with *%:%* and *%dopar%*:

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
cl <- makeCluster(2) 
registerDoParallel(cl)

foreach ( i = 1:3) %:%
  foreach ( j = 1:5) %dopar% { 
    resultA=matrix(c(1:6)*1,nrow=3)
    resultB=matrix(c(1:63)*1,nrow=3)
    resultC=matrix(c(1:12)*1,nrow=3)
    resultD=matrix(c(1:15)*1,nrow=3)
    data[[i,1,j]]=resultA 
    data[[i,2,j]]=resultB
    data[[i,3,j]]=resultC
    data[[i,4,j]]=resultD
  }
stopCluster(cl)
```

Unsurprisingly, the array is not populated in this variant, and I still lack the skill to set or define a correct .combine function.

I would appreciate any suggestions to solve the problem of combining the results A-B into the desired array. Avoiding the nested for-loops entirely could be the next step; however, I am mainly interested in getting the nested foreach and parallel processing running.

Comment: What does your desired output look like? Is it an array of four arrays? You have an iterator, but it isn't used, so I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: The data array is the desired result. In the example, the iterators would have created the results A-D but for simplification, the internals of the loops are not included. I struggle with how to combine the results to form the data array with the foreach function.